# PHP very odd outcome

Tags: php, explode

If I do this:

```
$comments = str_replace( "\n\n", "\n", $comments );
```

And this:

```
$comments = explode( "\n", $comments );
```

Then in a loop, how could this...

```
if( strlen( $comments[ $i ] ) == 0 )
```

...possibly be true???

There's not really any more context to it, it's pretty straight forward and I'm a long time PHP developer, this is really stumping me.

P.S. I've also tried something like...

```
$comments = str_replace( "\n\n\n", "\n", $comments );
$comments = str_replace( "\n\n", "\n", $comments );
$comments = str_replace( "\n\n", "\n", $comments );
```

...in succession and I still get the same issue.

Comment: what does the var_dump() of your $comments array tell you about your array? I normally use empty() rather than strlen()==0 too

Comment: 1. check if there is BR instead of \n; 2.if so replace it first; \r\n combination exits instead if \n\n, so try replacing that first; 4. you have to replace continious \n\n\n to unique \n using REGEX

Comment: replacing \r\n is not working either, and I just tried empty() instead of strlen() and that didn't work, something is up!

Comment: Just use `preg_replace` instead: `$comments = preg_replace("~\n{2,}~", "\n", $comments);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several other answers have pointed out the possibility of more than two adjacent line breaks.

Another easy way for an empty string to be part of the `explode` output would be an input string with a line break at the end:

```
"hey\n"
```

(this would also happen if it's `"\n\n"` there)

Running that through your code gives you the following array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "hey"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: BINGO! Damn I should have caught that, thank you, to many string ops today ;)

Answer (score 0):

If $comments contains \n\n\n then after replacement, it will be \n\n resulting in an empty element at explode.

Comment: Just call your str_replace twice, it will get rid of odd number of \n's.

Comment: And still have leftovers from `\n\n\n\n`, `\n\n\n\n\n` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Make sure $comments isn't an empty string

Comment: This "would" make the most sense, as my for loop is in another loop, but I just checked and $comments always has at least several lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$comments = str_replace( "<br>", "\r\n", $comments ); //incase if there is br , change to \n
$comments = trim($comments);
$comments = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $comments);
$comments = str_replace( "\n\n", "\n", $comments );
$comments = trim($comments);

$comments = explode( "\n", $comments );
```

and then

```
if( strlen( $comments[ $i ] ) == 0 )
```

Comment: This is no html in the string, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

I think most Regex/String functions only make a single pass. Hence something like:

```
str_replace("\n\n", "\n", "\n\n\n\n")
```

will give you

```
"\n\n"
```

because the replacement only goes through the string once, and not repeatedly until the replacee is no longer found. If you want to collapse multiple newlines, i think you could use:

```
preg_replace("[\\n]+", "\n", "\n\n\n\n")
```

if i remember my PHP regexes correctly. That would replace any contiguous set of 1 or more "\n"s with a single "\n"

Answer (score 0):

Safely get rid of any multiple of newlines. Takes out leading and trailing newlines with the trim.

```
while (strpos($comments, "\n\n") !== false)
    $comments = str_replace( "\n\n", "\n", trim($comments) );
```

Update: using preg_replace, it's possible to get a better clean - you can remove any empty lines which would be left in with the one above.

```
$comments = preg_replace("/\s*\n\n\s*/", "\n", trim($comments));
```

Comment: Just tried this, no dice, it still has an index that's empty.

Comment: Just tried a new string, got one that doesn't get caught by the str_replace. Updated post with a preg_replace that catches it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should account for both issues:

```
<?php
    $comments = "\nHello\n\n\nWorld\n\n\n\n\n";
    //replace two+ \n togheter for one \n
    $comments = preg_replace("/\n{2,}/", "\n", $comments);
    //remove if there's one at the beginning or end
    $comments = preg_replace("/(^\n|\n$)/", "", $comments);
    //should only have two elements
    print_r( explode("\n",$comments) );
?>
```